# AdMob shows only test ads and not real

Tags: android, admob

I add AdMob ads to my app (which is not published in play store)
but for some reason it only shows test ads and not real ones

In the control panel of AdMob indicates that ad requests are 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you publish your app on play store, real ads will not be visible to you. And after releasing on play store also, it takes 5-6 hours to load real ads. So you can release your app on internal, alpha or beta channel to make real ads visible. One more important thing is that if your test ads are visible that means you have done the coding right because test ads also use the same channel as the real ones.

Answer (score 0):

If it shows test Ads that is great, use the test ads to finish your app. Once you are done publish your app **Make sure to replace the ad unit id to the correct one**, it takes some time 6 to 24 hrs it really depends, but it will definitely work if you used the correct ids