# Admob ads are not loading

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

i have an app on the play store and lately i've been thinking about adding admob ads. So once they approved my profile I added "Interstitial" ads. I followed the procedure but the ads do not want to show and in fact this logcat appears here:

```
The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.
```

I would like to try to solve this problem, could you help me? I would be grateful! I'll post my code:

**Admob code in the Contacts Activity (mainactivity)**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });
    //
    Boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getBoolean("isFirstRun", true);
    if (isFirstRun) {
        //show start activity
        startActivity(new Intent(ContactsActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
    }
    getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            .putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).commit();
    //
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);

    MobileAds.initialize(this,
            "xx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxx"); //censored
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("xx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx");  //censored
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());


    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    }
    else{
        Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");

    }
```

**Build Gradle .app**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.conta.ftof"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.5"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false

           // proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0' // compreso
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.5.1' // compreso
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.1.9'
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:percent:29.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.5.0'


    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.0'  //compreso
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'   //compreso
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk:2.15.3'
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.6.0'

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.conta.ftof">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".donate" />
        <activity android:name=".VideoCallActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".CallingActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".FindPeopleActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".NotificationsActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ContactsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" />
        <activity android:name=".RegistrationActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />



                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="xx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxx"/> //censored

        <receiver android:name=".ReminderBroadcast"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

***if you help me I will put you as a solution quickly***

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63976245/8851971

Comment: @NadeemShaikh I try to wait until tomorrow.
a weird thing is the admob panel tells me there are 32 ad requests even if they don't load

Comment: @NadeemShaikh The ads still don't work, I think at this point I have something wrong with the code. could you help me find the error please?

Comment: Have you tried with the test ads?

Comment: @NadeemShaikh yes, it do not load same

Comment: please help me d

Comment: Where do you want to exactly show your add? Before opening SettingsActivity?